# Why is contentView property of NSWindow of type id?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nswindow

Why is the `contentView` property of the `NSWindow` class of type `id` instead of `NSView`

This does not make sense to me, why should the contentView be anything other than a `NSView` subclass.

So in my case I had to type it like this in order to access its frame:

```
NSView *contentView = self.window.contentView; // returns an `id`
CGRect frame = contentView.frame
```

Instead of this, which the compiler does not like:

```
CGRect frame =  self.window.contentView.frame; // This does not compile
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably historical. Objective-C supports strict typing, but it also supports "duck typing" in which you don't care what *class* an object is, you care what *messages* it responds to (i.e. if it looks like a duck and it quacks like a duck, it's probably a duck). You're allowed to type every object pointer as `id` and send whatever messages. Indeed, the receiver doesn't need to implement methods for *any* message it receives anyway: it can just as well forward the message to another object.

In Application Kit - the predecessor GUI framework to OpenStep and Cocoa - almost all objects were used through duck typing. Here's the (partial) interface for `Window` from version 3.2 of Application Kit.

```
@interface Window : Responder
{
  NXRect frame;
  id contentView;
  id delegate;
  id firstResponder;
  id lastLeftHit;
  id lastRightHit;
  id counterpart;
  id fieldEditor;
  int winEventMask;
  int windowNum;
  float backgroundGray;
  //some bit masks indicating whether the window is visible, is key etc.
}
-contentView;
-setContentView:aView;
//more methods
@end
```

Notice that the `contentView` ivar is defined to be an `id`, and that all of the types in the accessor methods are implicitly defined as `id` too (so `-setContentView:` returns an object: probably the `Window` instance `self`). That's how most Objective-C code in the early 1990s looked: Application Kit probably *was* most Objective-C code in the early 1990s.

`NSWindow` was introduced in the first version of AppKit - the GUI framework in what became Cocoa, back in 1994. AppKit generally uses more strict type declarations than Application Kit did, but it's not rigidly observed. Indeed it may even be the case that AppKit's `NSWindow` contains code from Application Kit's `Window`, and that this `contentView` ivar was not updated in the change.

Indeed, rigid requirement for type conformance in Objective-C variables is relatively recent. Most of the strictness was introduced either through property declarations (which are strongly typed except that C exists and supports casting), or through the change to protocols that allows optional methods, thus making it possible to strictly type delegate objects.

Comment: I have the feeling that the use of more and more static typing is a process going on for a longer time. When I came to the language (2002) it was already omnipresent. Apple's Objective-C Guide recommended its use as often as possible. If fact, it seemed that also Apple did use it for nearly every case where the language allowed it (exceptions being containers, initializers, delegates).

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. I think I can (well... have to) to live with a cast or a second line of code :-)

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe one of the first motivators was DO, which worked more efficiently when the root object conformed to a known protocol (as it meant the client didn't have to keep sending `respondsToSelector:` calls across the boundary): however that obviously didn't change _every_ case. It did mean people started using `void` as a method return type (so message sends across the boundary could be one way).

Answer (score 2):

The fact that `-[NSWindow contentView]` has `id` type is probably a relict of the early days of Cocoa and Objective-C.

Anyway: The compiler warnings are a result from the property-style syntax you are using to send messages. In Cocoa (as opposed to Cocoa-Touch) `window`, `contentView` and `frame` are not properties of their classes. That means you should use normal message sending syntax:

```
CGRect frame = [[[self window] contentView] frame];
```

This will work without compiler warnings.

Comment: No, the errors come from the fact that type 'id' does not have a proper method declaration shown in it's interface for dot-notation to take effect. Properties are not required to use dot-notation, I can call `NSObject.new` instead of `[NSObject new]` if I wanted to.

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III: You cannot send any messages (property accessor or non-property) to `id` typed variables using the dot syntax. But you can send any known selector using normal message sending syntax.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe: except in ARC mode if the selector hasn't been declared yet. That was a warning in manual memory management, but it's an error with ARC.

Answer (score -1):

It is for dynamic typing. A `NSWindow` does not really care if it's `contentView` is really a `NSView`, if it responds to the selectors it is sent. So, this way you could theoretically create your own class that doesn't inherit from `NSView` for displaying content and the compiler wouldn't choke.

Comment: The setter's signature is `- (void)setContentView:(NSView *)view` :(

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe correct, the problem is, however, it cannot implicitly convert allow you to use dot notation on an id, because not methods are defined in id's interface.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. `id` does not declare an interface. Anyway, for the sake of correctness, you should edit your answer according to Apple's documentation: `contentView` returns an `NSView`.